# Sorting xml data by date in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, sorting

I am getting a 'date' element from a RSS feed. I am having trouble with sorting and displaying the information. Can someone have a look? Thanks!

```
$('#feedContainer').empty();
                        $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: categoryURL,
                        dataType: 'xml',
                        success: function (xml) {
                                var data = [];
                                $(xml).find("item").each(function () {
                                  var dateText = $(this).find("Date").text().substr(0,5);
                                  var title = $(this).find("title").text();
                                  var region = date.substr(6);
                                        if (region.length < 3) { region = "ALL"; }  
                                  var description = $(this).find("description").text();
                                  var descriptdisplay = description.substr(0, description.indexOf(",")+6); //Parsed DATE from description
                                        if (descriptdisplay.length > 35) { descriptdisplay = "See event for details"; }
                                    //var locationdisplay = description.substr(description.indexOf(",")+6,4); //Parsed the location from description
                                  var category = $(this).find("category").text();
                                  var linkUrl = $(this).find("link").text();
                                  var item={ title: $(this).find("title").text(), dateText: $(this).find("Date").text().substr(0,5), date : new Date( dateText) }  
                                  data.push(item);
                                 // var displaytitle = "<a href='" + linkUrl + "' target='_blank'>" + title + "</a>" ;
                                 // $('#feedContainer').append('<h3>'+displaytitle+'</h3><p>'+"Event Date: "+descriptdisplay+'</p><p>'+"Location: "+region+'</p');
                                  data.sort(function(a,b){ return a.date > b.date;});
                                $.each(data, function(index, item) { $('#feedContainer').append('<h3>'+item.title+'</h3><p>'+"Event Date: "+item.dateText+'</p><p>'+"Location: "+item.date+'</p'); });
                            });

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting date objects, try sorting the epoch timestamp instead:

```
data.sort(function(a,b){ 
   return a.date.getTime() > b.date.getTime();
});
```

Comment: okay, I just gave this a shot. Data did not display. Do I need to add any code else where? Also, the date element is in ddmmyy format. Does this make a difference?

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is still not displaying. Thank you for helping with this problem, I really appreciate it.

Comment: What happened when you used the code in the fiddle, where there any alerts ?

Comment: There were no alerts. I plugged the url of the rss feed in and ran the script.

Comment: I also took the script and lugged it into my source code and ran it. Nothing displayed.

Comment: I'm using Dreamweaver, how do I locate the console log information?

Comment: Use a browser, like chrome, and hit F12

Comment: ok here we go: Uncaught ReferenceError: date is not defined indexA.html:68
Denying load of chrome-extension://ganlifbpkcplnldliibcbegplfmcfigp/scripts/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.map. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension. indexA.html:1

Comment: Line 68 im ny code is:             var region = date.substr(6);

Comment: I removed the region variable and ran it. the function is running and displaying! However the alert you put in place displayed about 30 times. So it definitely a problem with the date format.... A couple FYIs the webmaster created the 'date'element on about 30 or so "events" so not all of them have the newly added element. Second:  the element sometimes contains a region as well. For example: ddmmyySCV, other times it will just be ddmmyy. Could this be the problem it?

Comment: If you're going to pass the date string to javascripts date() function, it could indeed be a problem as that function is rather picky and should be passed only valid date strings. There's a page on MDN on valid javascript dates, but I couldn't find it right now.

Comment: Is this it? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date